# Texture transparency does not work as intended

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was making a texture pack for 1.14.4 in Minecraft. Once, I decided to mess around with the `stone.png` texture. I made it green, and got this:
[image: The green stone]

Next, I made it transparent:

[image: transparent]

The stone was still green, but black when viewed from an angle.
It was supposed to be transparent everywhere it was.
Please fix this.

*Please tell me if this is a **repeat of a question.***

Comment: "Please fix this"? We are not a service - please fix that. On-topic: your character's hand seems transparent as well. Did you change that texture? Could that shine a light on the problem you are having?

Comment: That was on my skin, not my texture pack

Comment: I don't see any black blocks. But that doesn't matter for the problem anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The block model of stone does not allow for transparent textures. You need to also change the block model, for example you could copy the one of glass.
Note that this might have weird results on chunk loading, because the game does not expect you to be able to look through stone.

Comment: If i change `model` in `stone.json` to `block/glass`, can I make stone look the way I intended it to be?